# Days with a torus shaped Sun

Tags: science-based, astronomy, astrophysics

What would day and night look like on Earth (or any habitable planet), if the sun was torus shaped, with the same circumference?

And moreover, how much the Earth will be affected, if the sun was rotating on y-axis, vertically?

Additional info if it helps:

- The sun is seen from the earth, as a torus.

Comment: And what would be the axis of rotation of this sun?

Comment: Sorry my bad... for not specifying the axis. Hope it's a little bit clear now.

Comment: a little bit more clarity is needed - how the sun is seen from the Earth - as a torus, or as an oblong rectangle (a torus laying on its side)? Also, how would the visible size of this torus correspond to visible size of the Sun today?

Comment: I'd say, the sun is seen from the Earth as a torus. (Let me make that clarification in the main post as well.)

And regarding the second question, well, unfortunately, physics or astronomy is not the field I'm majoring in, so I don't much about it, either.

But in any case, if the following helps.... just imagine our solar system, and make the sun a torus, and everything else is pretty much the same. Like, the size of the torus, and its distance from every other planets, is the same as the original sun.

Comment: Oh, and if this helps too, I'd additionally like to add that I want the torus sun to look almost similar to how the original sun looks from Earth, during an eclipse.

Comment: On Earth, brightness of the day and warmness of the summer depend on how luminous is the Sun, and that depends on its visible size. If Sun turns into a torus which is exactly the same circumference as the old Sun, then its luminosity would decrease, and Earth would become colder. How much decrease - depends on how thick is this torus.

Comment: Okay, so the temperature of the Earth depends on the thickness of the torus, right?

Comment: The temperature of the Earth depends on how much the Sun's surface is radiating _toward_ Earth and the amount of energy/surface the Sun is producing. If you make your Sun like a torus, (a) the surface of the Sun will increase, so (assuming the Sun produces the same amount of energy) its temperature will decrease and (b) less of the Sun's surface will face _straight_ towards Earth (e.g. the surface of torus central hole won't radiate straight towards Earth).

Comment: if the sun has the same circumference as now but it is shaped like a torus then either the density has to at least triple (i think) or all of the planets wouldn't be where they are today.

Comment: to stay stable as a torus under the laws of gravity. that object needs to spin incredibly fast. i am not sure if that would allow for stellar formation.

Comment: to answer this question properly one would need the major radius, the minor radius, and the average luminosity per surface area.

Comment: It is unclear what orientation you have in mind, and what the Earth's orbit looks like. Generally, this is going to difficult to answer: the sun has partially transparent layers, and the light is produced within. If you fix the sun's power and volume but distribute it over a torus rather than sphere, it will likely  be *brighter* when viewed from above (ie when the sun-torus looks like an O), this is because the light produced within has to travel through less of the sun's material to escape. Since the torus is rotating, there will also be radiation due to the moving plasma

Comment: This is a tough question because my first thought is, the Earth would not experience day or night, it would just stop existing as it is engulfed by the super nova your star created as the laws of the universe go WTF and fix themselves violently.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"how much the Earth will be affected, if the sun was rotating on y-axis, vertically?"*

**Solar seasons**

Depends on the thickness of the torus, but assuming the sun looks flatter or rounder, it  would cause variation in the amount of solar energy that reaches the planet. A periodic variation in effective sunlight will cause *solar seasons* on all planets. These solar seasons will be superimposed on the seasons your planet already experiences from its tilted axis. Some winters become extremely cold, some summers could be extremely warm, because of the  additional effect of *sun phase*.

**Danger, depending on the sun's internals**

Certain harmful types of radiation/ionization could occur in the plane of the torus. An asymmetric sun, rotating extremely fast, can emit dangerous, high speed flares that reach the planet atmosphere. When the torus is visible as a rectangle (the planet being in the plane of the torus) more of these events will occur.

Answer (score 0):

## Colder

The light we receive from the Sun depends on its temperature and its apparent size in the sky, but not much else.  For example, the edges of the Sun don't seem bright, because even though we are looking at a much larger surface area, we're seeing it at an angle.  If we were nearer to the Sun it would take up more size in the sky, but any individual part would seem the same brightness, just as a light bulb doesn't seem like it gets brighter if you closer to it.

Your torus model is a Sun with a hole, or a Sun that has the same radius in one direction but much less (unspecified) in another.  So we get much less light.  For reference, Mars is at 1.52 AU; the inverse square is 43%, and a little outside of the habitable zone.  If your torus occupies less than half the apparent area of the Sun, your Earth will be in deep trouble.  Something much less dramatic will still cause an Ice Age, at least - even [esoteric variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles) in Earth's real orbit and axial tilt have been blamed for as much.

If your Sun is rotating *very rapidly* so that Doppler effect is relevant, this answer could change, but I'm not sure in what direction.  I don't seriously have a model for a toroidal star.  I'm also assuming the surface temperature (color) is the same as ours; if you make it a hotter star you can compensate, at the cost of a bluer sunset.